# Android “fake having a locked phone” - Galaxy SII

Tags: screen

I have a work-mandatory email-app on my phone that won't work unless it detects that you have a passcode locked phone.

I have a rooted Galaxy S2 Android phone (Cyanogenmod 10) and am wondering if there are any apps or ways of tricking my phone into thinking it has a 4 digit pin code when it doesn't.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to bypass your workplace policy? Wouldn't it be better to have a chat with the sysadmin and see if you both can arrive at something that both of you are happy with.

Comment: If you enter your pin code wrong too many times, it factory resets your entire phone... which happened to me 3 days ago. It was one of the Sys Admin that suggested I could do this (I know him as a friend... he would not have said it while at work).

Comment: "Don't do that" :P

Answer (score 2):

CM's profiles may work for you. I use it for circumventing the mandatory lockscreen if a certificate is installed (CaCert's regular SSL root CA here).

To set it up tap *disabled* in:
settings->profiles->default->lockscreen

For others: This only works with the alternative CyanogenMod aftermarket firmware.

Comment: Thank  you very much! :) settings->profiles->default->lockscreen->disabled does the trick.

Comment: Thank you so much! I went with the "insecure" setting, because I like having to swipe to unlock. I just didn't want to have to enter a PIN.