# Android fake "having a pin/password protected phone" (lock-screen)

Tags: root-access, lock-screens

I have a rooted android phone and want a specific app to believe that I have configured a device pin (or fingerprint) to lock the phone, basically the same as this guy:
[Android “fake having a locked phone” - Galaxy SII](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32846/android-fake-having-a-locked-phone-galaxy-sii?newreg=8eef18da17c148909e88eefde1d5ec3d)

Caveat: no cyanogenmod. Is there a setting/app/way to achieve this without CM?

Comment: i dont want to revert magisk modifications, i want the app to beleive that an android screen lock is configured, even thou it aint

Comment: I think you miss my point: the app I want to use wants to force me to use a pin or screen lock pattern (for security) - even on a non-rooted phone. I want to trick the app into beleiving that I *am* using a screen-lock. this is not possible on a non-rooted phone. but I suspect it should be possible on a rooted phone.

Comment: Sorry the "locked" term in the title got me on the wrong path. If faking a lock screen protected is possible or not depends to my knowledge on the app. There are explicit checks where the app simply asks if lock screen pin/password has been configured and there are implicit checks where the app uses a feature which requires you to have a  pin/password configured. The first can be bypassed using an Xposed module (not sure if such an module exists), but the latter are difficult to bypass as it is required  for the function. Most users "bypass" the lock screen PIN by using the fingerprint reader.

Comment: thanks, https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/mod-xposed-lockscreen-disabler-smartlock.2587192/ looks very promising, I'll give that a try

Comment: Please only test such solutions if you willing to reset your user data. The linked solution is very old, at that time device encryption wasn't enforced. Nowadays all devices are encrypted by default and the PIN/password has to be entered at least once after reboot for being able to access your data. If a mod like this now removes the PIN entering then this may lead to inaccessible user data.